# Proof of work login instead of captcha

Tags: captcha

I've just seen this genius script on github:

https://github.com/jsavoie/proof-of-work-login

My question is: Why is POW login not a world standard right now in 2018? It's absolute Genius!

Why are old fashioned captchas and recaptchas still so widespread?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The current going rate for reCaptcha solves is upwards of $3 per 1000.  Meanwhile, the going rate for a t2.large spot instance is 2.78 cents per hour, dual cores with burst capability.  So, for a proof of work to have the same attack cost as reCaptcha, the POW would have to take well over a minute, maybe two, on a single core of 3GHz.  You're looking at possibly as much as 5min on an iphone 6.  Most users would prefer to click signs.

Comment: Notice that you can add proof-of-work to every request, invisible from user, if you do it simple enough, and I doubt that you can force user to enter CAPTCHA in every request. You can do proof of work just complex enough for client machine to spend more resources to send request than server machine spends to process request and send response. I think `Proof of work` is a great DDOS deterrent

Answer (score 3):

Real-world data shows that the difficulty levels associated with Proof-of-Work would mean that significant numbers of legitimate users would be unable to continue their current levels of activity.

It seems to be a classic example of security over usability.

[Source](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~rnc1/proofwork.pdf)

Comment: Is selecting store fronts, hills, bridges, street signs.. from a set of pictures usable? I find it ridiculous. I'd prefer to wait for my CPU to find the right nonce.

Comment: I guess you can allow user to choose between a reCaptcha and a POW log in. Still, if I need to wait for more than half a minute on average for a POW to complete, I much rather click traffic signals.

Comment: When i used my computer in my school network, google was annoyed at all of us using 100 computers under the same ip, so captcha was in maximum difficulty. Every single time I done it carefully but google rejected the solution 12 times straight.

Answer (score 2):

The Main Purpose of Recaptcha is to prevent automated Bots,
Preventing Spam is an obvious outcome of Recaptcha as Bots are usually used for Spamming, Though proof-of-work can prevent spamming (By making process slow) It doesn't actually stop bots, It might be used as a seperate mechanism but It by no way is a replacement to Recaptcha as Recaptcha is to detect Humans

Comment: It doesn't stop bots. But it does slow them down in a very useful west. That is until they get very fast.  PoW algorithms would keep needing to be updated to cater for this.  Meanwhile older  and legitimate users with slower computers would suffer

Comment: @hookenz I hope you meant that PoW doesn't stop bots, because ReCAPTCHA does, we can use click farms, but they are real humans, so, it does what it's meant to do.